# How to change the subject when sending email using crontab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have my crontab configured as

```
MAILTO=example@gmail.com

#1am every day (EST)
00 05 * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/mongo_backup.sh
```

which sends me email with the subject

```
Cron <ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX> /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/mongo_backup.sh
```

But I need with some custom date

```
<Date> MyProjectName
```

Comment: do any of these methods work on your system?  [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50424331/10304821),  [link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/56497/how-to-modify-a-cronjob-email-subject)

Comment: I would try [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/56497/how-to-modify-a-cronjob-email-subject) as this is exactly what you would like to do :)

Comment: @Milag Tried that did not work.

Comment: @LucioRandy Tried that did not work. – Profer just now   Edit

Comment: Hi, I think you can't change the subject of MAILTO of a cronjob. One workaround would be sending a mail manually in your .sh or in the cronjob command. Take a look at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line) to learn how to configure `ssmtp` or `mail`. Before you use these commands in the crontab, make sure they are working properly (try to send mails from the command line). Then you can follow link2 that @Milag posted. I tried it by myself and it worked.

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/56497/how-to-modify-a-cronjob-email-subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Better of doing it with a mail package in your os as following.** it will also pipe any error output of your mongo_backup script to email as message and email subject will be current date-time.

```
00 05 * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/mongo_backup.sh 2>&1 | mail -s $(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") example@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the actual date in your message or subject use the date instruction between backquote:

> `date`

For example this script will send the current date as subject:

> echo "Current date is in the subject of this message" | mail xxx@mydomain.org -s "send at `date`"

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linux inbuilt Mail User Agent Utility - mailx, it can also pipe the output of your shell script, if any, to the specified mail-id.

```
00 05 * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/mongo_backup.sh | mailx -m -s "$(date +\%Y\%m\%d) MyProjectName" <User-ID here> 2>/dev/null
```